# actual-<"null">,expected-<"null"> mismatch with XMLUnit

Tags: xmlunit

XMLUnit tries to match correct Entity elements (i.e. with correct attributes), but getting actual-<"null">,expected-<"null"> mismatch at <"Entity"> nodename.

```
    String expected = "<Object>" +
            "<Entity id=\"Entity1\">" +
            "expected1" +
            "</Entity>" +
            "<Entity id=\"Entity2\">" +
            "expected2" +
            "</Entity>" +
            "</Object>";
    String actual = "<Object>" +
            "<Entity id=\"Entity2\">" +
            "expected2" +
            "</Entity>" +
            "<Entity id=\"Entity1\">" +
            "expected1" +
            "</Entity>" +
            "</Object>";
```

Whats the issue here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please expand what you are doing, who is emitting the text you cite?  When I create a `Diff` with your examples with `ElementNameAndAttributeQualifier` I get a similar result (not identical because the node order is different), which is what I'd expect.

Comment: Yeah! its to do with node order.

Answer (score 0):

Its to do with node order. Its tough to find that with final output of mismatch detail. But I was able to see that with `DifferenceListener.differenceFound(Difference difference)`. And we can suppress that by catching `DifferenceConstances.CHILD_NODELIST_SEQUENCE_ID` i.e. `return DifferenceListener.RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_IDENTICAL;`